# Temporarily switch working copy to a specific Git commit

Tags: git, commit, temporary

How to switch to specific Git commit **without losing all the commits made after it**?

I want that local files will be changed, but commits' database will remain intact, only the current position pointer is set to currently selected commit.

I want to change files' state to specific commit, run project and, when finished, restore files back to last commit.

How to do this without zipping the whole project's folder?

Comment: Related: [Revert to a previous Git commit](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4114095/456814).

Answer (score 458, accepted):

If you are at a certain branch `mybranch`, just go ahead and `git checkout commit_hash`. Then you can return to your branch by `git checkout mybranch`. I had the same game bisecting a bug today :) Also, you should know about [git bisect](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Debugging-with-Git#_binary_search).

Comment: Note you can just do `git checkout commit_hash` if you are on a clean repository and not need to do branching. Might be easier for some use cases (like mine).

Comment: @enderland: your HEAD always points at some branch, normally :)

Comment: I've had an issue where I had to use the whole commit hash because a partial one wasn't accepted.

Comment: Upvote for the `git bisect` reference; what an extremely useful tool!

Comment: Since Git 2.23 you can also use ```git switch -``` to return to your original branch

Comment: @Niek would it be less of a confusing tool if one is familiar with binary search? seems a pretty useful, simple tool to me. why is it confusing?

Comment: @Fed Are you replying to the wrong person? I never used the word 'confusing'.

Comment: @Niek yes my bad, don't know what happened there

Answer (score 76):

First, use `git log` to see the log, pick the commit you want, note down the sha1 hash that is used to identify the commit. Next, run `git checkout hash`. After you are done, `git checkout original_branch`. This has the advantage of not moving the HEAD, it simply switches the working copy to a specific commit.

Comment: I think you mean `git checkout <original_branch>`. `git checkout HEAD` is effectively a NOOP

Comment: `git reset --hard <hash>` changes the HEAD of the current branch, while with `git checkout <hash>` you get a detached checkout which does not change any branch, and you can easily return without knowing the original hash ID of your branch as shown in this answer.

Comment: @Femaref Beginner's question: given the context of this question (switch to an earlier commit temporarily), why would it be an advantage or disadvantage to move or not move the HEAD ?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty Assuming my edit is approved, it should answer your question. HEAD actually gets moved in any event; but in a checkout the branch reference HEAD points to is not itself moved.

Answer (score 33):

In addition to the other answers here showing you how to `git checkout <the-hash-you-want>` it's worth knowing you can switch back to where you were using:

```
git checkout @{-1}
```

This is often more convenient than:

```
git checkout what-was-that-original-branch-called-again-question-mark
```

As you might anticipate, `git checkout @{-2}` will take you back to the branch you were at two `git checkout`s ago, and similarly for other numbers. If you can remember where you were for bigger numbers, you should get some kind of medal for that.

---

Sadly for productivity, `git checkout @{1}` does not take you to the branch you will be on in future, which is a shame.

Comment: Note that `git checkout -` is a shorthand alias for `git checkout @{-1}`

Comment: @Nathanael **OMGOD**, _no way_ … this changes everything! Nice, thank you! … I was going to incorporate this in the answer, but I think it's also useful to know about the general `@{n}` syntax, as it works with lots of git commands. I found it hard to add your shorthand without making the answer rather confusing. Instead I've voted up your comment – I hope people will see it. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. This discussion is tangential to the actual question anyway. More of a bonus! I often use the same syntax for merging features into a release. e.g. `git merge -` to merge the branch you had last checked out into the currently checked out branch. It's like `cd -` in bash.