# Temporarily switch working copy to previous revision in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

This is basically the same question as [Temporarily switch working copy to a specific Git commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230469/temporarily-switch-working-copy-to-a-specific-git-commit), *but for Mercurial*.

Say revision 500 is the last revision I've committed in Mercurial. I've worked some more, and realized something went wrong in an earlier revision. So, I've "git stashed", that is, `hg shelve`d my current changes, so I am at a clean revision 500.

Now what I want to do is checkout revision 499, rebuild software, see if it still has error; if it does, checkout revision 498, rebuild software, see if it still has error; if it does, revision 497, rebuild software, see if it still has error; etc etc until I figure out which revision introduced the error.

Once I'm done with that, I want to go back to revision 500, `unshelve` my previous work, add to that a fix, and then make a new commit (which would be revision 501). That means when I go back in history I don't want to reset anything, nor stage anything from there.

In git I can just do `git checkout HASH` to go back in history, and once done, `git checkout master` to go back to the tip. **Which commands should I use in Mercurial?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mercurial — revert back to old version and continue from there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540454/mercurial-revert-back-to-old-version-and-continue-from-there)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can go to older revisions using hg update:

```
hg update 499  # The short id number or the full hash
```

or alternatively if you want to step to the parent changeset  without needing to know the id, you can use a mercurial revset:

```
hg update .~1
```

once you have identified your issue you can simply:

```
hg update tip
```

and unshelve your changes, add your fix and commit.

I recommend you read the Mercurial: The Definitive Guide. Your question very basic / entry level mercurial usage.

Edit: the link to Mercurial: Definitive Guide is:

http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/

or the 1.9 version of the boook:

https://book.mercurial-scm.org/read/index.html